# Facebook Share and asking always for the account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-login

I'm developing an app that will be in an iPad and will be used by everyone who comes to the  market. I was thinking about a 20% offer if people share our website in their Facebook. So thats why i want a button that ask for their Facebook account and then share some content.

In addition, the ipad will be in Guided Access Mode, so users can't go to setting and set their Facebook account, that's why I want them to login every time they press the button.

Is it possible?

At this moment I'm using this code but doesn't work, i need them to login every time.

```
SLComposeViewController *fbVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

[fbVC setInitialText:@"Pick D Pack: Message"];
[fbVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.pickdpack.com"]];
[fbVC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

[self presentViewController:fbVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope anyone understand me and help me,

Thanks

Comment: It is against Facebook Platform Policy ( https://developers.facebook.com/policy ).  5.4: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i've found the answer :)

I've used a UIWebView to load the Facebook and Twitter Share and when the user clicks on the close button i've added this code to the button trigger to clear the cache.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in 
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Thanks for all anyway :)